# How can I read a json file in Angular through VS CODE and make it appear in Localhost

Tags: json, angular

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,



}
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import sampleData from './data.json';
import { AuthenticationService } from './_services/authentication.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ProjetOpenGov';
Users: any = sampleData;
  public countryList: any;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {}

  deco() {
    this.authenticationService.logout();
    location.reload(true);
  }

  goToLog() {
    this.router.navigate(['/authentification/login']);
  }
}
```

**json-typings.d.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as data from './data.json';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {


}





   declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
    }
```

**data.json**

```
  { 
   "version":"2.0",
   "class":"dataset",
   "label":"Dette publique brute",
   "source":"ESTAT",
   "updated":"2019-10-22T11:00:00+0200",
   "value":{ 
      "1102":"141245.5",
      "1103":"147154.2",
      "1104":"151295.9",
      "1105":"152688.1",
      "1106":"157985.4",
      "1107":"174403.5",
      "1108":"180270.0",
      "1109":"184674.5",
      "1110":"201809.9",
      "1111":"230014.6",
      "1112":"244696.8",
      "1113":"255683.8",
      "1114":"261040.8",
      "1115":"263229.5",
      "1116":"280001.0",
      "1117":"292264.6",
      "1118":"296203.2",
      "1119":"289843.1",
      "1120":"285287.3",
      "741":"280959.5",
      "742":"286055.5",
      "743":"288110.8",
      "744":"285866.7",
      "745":"288418.8",
      "746":"294975.3",
      "747":"297494.9",
      "748":"300063.7",
      "749":"327683.2",
      "750":"347223.7",
      "751":"364132.1",
      "752":"389106.6",
      "753":"404752.3",
      "754":"414432.4",
      "755":"431159.3",
      "756":"438233.3",
      "757":"451396.0",
      "758":"454293.3",
      "759":"460038.7",
      "760":"10168.5",
      "761":"10269.8",
      "762":"8890.3",
      "763":"8126.5",
      "764":"7526.2",
      "765":"6388.6",
      "766":"5721.0",
      "767":"5296.9",
      "768":"4847.5",
      "769":"5111.5",
      "770":"5856.1",
      "771":"6284.2",
      "772":"7004.9",
      "773":"7147.0",
      "774":"11618.5",
      "775":"11871.1",
      "776":"14244.8",
      "777":"13246.6",
      "778":"12491.5",
      "969":"6024.4",
      "970":"6660.8",
      "971":"7339.8",
      "972":"8184.8",
      "973":"9055.8",
      "974":"9595.8",
      "975":"9597.7",
      "976":"9461.8",
      "977":"8658.6",
      "978":"10139.0",
      "979":"10953.7",
      "980":"13057.9",
      "981":"15618.5",
      "982":"18706.5",
      "983":"19013.8",
      "984":"19164.1",
      "985":"19509.3",
      "986":"18814.1",
      "987":"21256.3",
      "779":"11567.8",
      "780":"18322.2",
      "781":"22013.9",
      "782":"24540.2",
      "783":"28681.7",
      "784":"31390.0",
      "785":"35406.7",
      "786":"39608.1",
      "787":"42300.2",
      "788":"49826.8",
      "789":"59062.5",
      "790":"62298.5",
      "791":"71783.6",
      "792":"67102.2",
      "793":"65588.5",
      "794":"67951.6",
      "795":"64945.2",
      "796":"68515.1",
      "797":"67435.9",
      "817":"1245750.4",
      "818":"1258694.4",
      "819":"1312355.3",
      "820":"1400120.9",
      "821":"1470360.1",
      "822":"1541096.9",
      "823":"1590959.4",
      "824":"1599567.6",
      "825":"1668517.4",
      "826":"1785140.9",
      "827":"2112594.8",
      "828":"2149488.6",
      "829":"2227418.8",
      "830":"2213008.7",
      "831":"2215168.4",
      "832":"2185113.2",
      "833":"2168989.3",
      "834":"2118963.4",
      "835":"2069007.1",
      "798":"93084.0",
      "799":"89464.7",
      "800":"93174.5",
      "801":"89061.4",
      "802":"89394.7",
      "803":"79532.5",
      "804":"71183.3",
      "805":"63755.0",
      "806":"80547.5",
      "807":"92986.6",
      "808":"103472.9",
      "809":"114452.4",
      "810":"114025.7",
      "811":"113943.4",
      "812":"117801.4",
      "813":"108532.4",
      "814":"105083.1",
      "815":"103810.9",
      "816":"101681.5",
      "722":"4844944.9",
      "723":"4998471.4",
      "724":"5164189.7",
      "725":"5417845.2",
      "726":"5674946.8",
      "727":"5937564.1",
      "728":"6075942.8",
      "729":"6187025.4",
      "730":"6695531.7",
      "731":"7431671.3",
      "732":"8167252.7",
      "733":"8577327.8",
      "734":"8908395.5",
      "735":"9184338.0",
      "736":"9418985.4",
      "737":"9544422.9",
      "738":"9721962.8",
      "739":"9812900.0",
      "740":"9914595.5",
      "703":"4847857.0",
      "704":"5001656.7",
      "705":"5167555.4",
      "706":"5421240.2",
      "707":"5678351.3",
      "708":"5941266.0",
      "709":"6080094.7",
      "710":"6191635.1",
      "711":"6700293.8",
      "712":"7439199.8",
      "713":"8177403.5",
      "714":"8588957.0",
      "715":"8921659.6",
      "716":"9197888.7",
      "717":"9433813.0",
      "718":"9560364.2",
      "719":"9737487.7",
      "720":"9829530.3",
      "721":"9930020.6",
      "836":"315.6",
      "837":"333.4",
      "838":"442.9",
      "839":"489.7",
      "840":"499.9",
      "841":"533.1",
      "842":"628.1",
      "843":"617.5",
      "844":"749.4",
      "845":"1023.1",
      "846":"981.9",
      "847":"1027.4",
      "848":"1762.5",
      "849":"1934.2",
      "850":"2129.9",
      "851":"2077.4",
      "852":"2216.3",
      "853":"2219.2",
      "854":"2174.2",
      "874":"148217.0",
      "875":"162971.0",
      "876":"171410.0",
      "877":"181510.0",
      "878":"199282.0",
      "879":"213976.0",
      "880":"225730.0",
      "881":"239915.0",
      "882":"264775.0",
      "883":"301062.0",
      "884":"330570.0",
      "885":"356235.0",
      "886":"305085.0",
      "887":"320498.0",
      "888":"319629.0",
      "889":"311729.0",
      "890":"315009.0",
      "891":"317484.0",
      "892":"334721.0",
      "893":"374557.0",
      "894":"378883.0",
      "895":"384145.0",
      "896":"382775.0",
      "897":"389888.0",
      "898":"393479.0",
      "899":"392132.0",
      "900":"384662.0",
      "901":"440621.0",
      "902":"569535.0",
      "903":"649153.0",
      "904":"743043.0",
      "905":"889909.0",
      "906":"977312.0",
      "907":"1039388.0",
      "908":"1070080.0",
      "909":"1104554.0",
      "910":"1145098.0",
      "911":"1173303.0",
      "684":"5852187.2",
      "685":"6023457.6",
      "686":"6194837.7",
      "687":"6458563.7",
      "688":"6840165.8",
      "689":"7202782.7",
      "690":"7437857.7",
      "691":"7541278.4",
      "692":"8003094.3",
      "693":"9092239.4",
      "694":"10194369.3",
      "695":"10825004.8",
      "696":"11363152.5",
      "697":"11708562.6",
      "698":"12216606.9",
      "699":"12576131.2",
      "700":"12514237.1",
      "701":"12613301.8",
      "702":"12750484.6",
      "665":"5860628.2",
      "666":"6033116.6",
      "667":"6205229.1",
      "668":"6470178.2",
      "669":"6853365.3",
      "670":"7217895.8",
      "671":"7453379.2",
      "672":"7557726.0",
      "673":"8021611.1",
      "674":"9114290.6",
      "675":"10220108.4",
      "676":"10853462.8",
      "677":"11393818.8",
      "678":"11743821.8",
      "679":"12253267.7",
      "680":"12613676.7",
      "681":"12551844.5",
      "682":"12651718.4",
      "683":"12789080.9",
      "1216":"57926.0",
      "1217":"59187.0",
      "1218":"59661.0",
      "1219":"64870.0",
      "1220":"67697.0",
      "1221":"65759.0",
      "1222":"65894.0",
      "1223":"63425.0",
      "1224":"63254.0",
      "1225":"75482.0",
      "1226":"88248.0",
      "1227":"95576.0",
      "1228":"107801.0",
      "1229":"114888.0",
      "1230":"123778.0",
      "1231":"133287.0",
      "1232":"136249.0",
      "1233":"137391.0",
      "1234":"138412.0",
      "912":"870626.0",
      "913":"897446.0",
      "914":"956794.0",
      "915":"1050356.0",
      "916":"1123615.0",
      "917":"1189919.0",
      "918":"1194106.0",
      "919":"1252867.0",
      "920":"1370326.0",
      "921":"1607983.0",
      "922":"1701122.0",
      "923":"1807957.0",
      "924":"1892540.0",
      "925":"1977734.0",
      "926":"2039884.0",
      "927":"2101255.0",
      "928":"2188481.0",
      "929":"2258656.0",
      "930":"2315266.0",
      "931":"8441.0",
      "932":"9659.0",
      "933":"10391.4",
      "934":"11614.6",
      "935":"13199.5",
      "936":"15113.1",
      "937":"15521.5",
      "938":"16447.5",
      "939":"18516.9",
      "940":"22051.2",
      "941":"25739.1",
      "942":"28458.0",
      "943":"30666.3",
      "944":"35259.6",
      "945":"36662.5",
      "946":"37548.6",
      "947":"37610.3",
      "948":"38419.6",
      "949":"38599.2",
      "1045":"28008.4",
      "1046":"32818.1",
      "1047":"41007.4",
      "1048":"42348.3",
      "1049":"50505.1",
      "1050":"54075.6",
      "1051":"62286.9",
      "1052":"66491.1",
      "1053":"73303.8",
      "1054":"76515.9",
      "1055":"79101.1",
      "1056":"72869.9",
      "1057":"77519.4",
      "1058":"78871.9",
      "1059":"79564.9",
      "1060":"83814.7",
      "1061":"87440.7",
      "1062":"91204.4",
      "1063":"93311.8",
      "855":"39096.3",
      "856":"40538.4",
      "857":"41538.4",
      "858":"43559.8",
      "859":"44055.8",
      "860":"44379.0",
      "861":"43692.5",
      "862":"47147.9",
      "863":"79621.0",
      "864":"104685.5",
      "865":"144229.9",
      "866":"189726.8",
      "867":"210036.3",
      "868":"215352.0",
      "869":"203378.0",
      "870":"201654.1",
      "871":"200708.5",
      "872":"201363.0",
      "873":"205977.6",
      "950":"1353522.0",
      "951":"1419963.5",
      "952":"1436096.8",
      "953":"1471273.3",
      "954":"1526321.4",
      "955":"1591537.0",
      "956":"1657310.1",
      "957":"1677375.7",
      "958":"1738314.9",
      "959":"1838882.7",
      "960":"1920305.1",
      "961":"1973121.3",
      "962":"2055061.0",
      "963":"2135820.8",
      "964":"2202818.6",
      "965":"2239303.8",
      "966":"2285254.1",
      "967":"2328697.2",
      "968":"2380305.7",
      "1007":"2912.1",
      "1008":"3185.2",
      "1009":"3365.7",
      "1010":"3395.1",
      "1011":"3404.5",
      "1012":"3701.9",
      "1013":"4151.9",
      "1014":"4609.7",
      "1015":"4762.1",
      "1016":"7528.5",
      "1017":"10150.9",
      "1018":"11629.2",
      "1019":"13264.1",
      "1020":"13550.8",
      "1021":"14827.6",
      "1022":"15941.3",
      "1023":"15524.9",
      "1024":"16630.4",
      "1025":"15425.1",
      "1026":"1672.2",
      "1027":"1736.6",
      "1028":"1768.3",
      "1029":"1817.9",
      "1030":"2051.9",
      "1031":"2217.1",
      "1032":"2630.1",
      "1033":"2868.2",
      "1034":"5684.6",
      "1035":"5815.7",
      "1036":"7951.0",
      "1037":"8074.5",
      "1038":"9699.7",
      "1039":"11009.6",
      "1040":"11330.5",
      "1041":"11446.9",
      "1042":"11024.4",
      "1043":"12696.6",
      "1044":"12609.7",
      "988":"1011.0",
      "989":"1304.4",
      "990":"1251.5",
      "991":"1370.5",
      "992":"1561.7",
      "993":"1566.8",
      "994":"1647.7",
      "995":"1834.6",
      "996":"4392.4",
      "997":"6767.7",
      "998":"8414.2",
      "999":"8795.7",
      "1000":"9178.3",
      "1001":"8984.4",
      "1002":"9668.5",
      "1003":"8953.3",
      "1004":"10091.6",
      "1005":"10352.4",
      "1006":"10600.6",
      "1064":"2654.0",
      "1065":"2989.2",
      "1066":"2927.3",
      "1067":"3267.4",
      "1068":"3449.6",
      "1069":"3606.4",
      "1070":"3472.9",
      "1071":"3584.6",
      "1072":"3837.0",
      "1073":"4152.7",
      "1074":"4452.1",
      "1075":"4796.6",
      "1076":"4855.1",
      "1077":"5226.6",
      "1078":"5390.0",
      "1079":"5586.2",
      "1080":"5739.9",
      "1081":"5682.1",
      "1082":"5641.1",
      "1083":"235339.0",
      "1084":"238241.0",
      "1085":"244476.0",
      "1086":"256293.0",
      "1087":"266142.0",
      "1088":"274332.0",
      "1089":"264180.0",
      "1090":"266127.0",
      "1091":"353931.0",
      "1092":"354704.0",
      "1093":"378698.0",
      "1094":"401243.0",
      "1095":"432354.0",
      "1096":"446841.0",
      "1097":"455632.0",
      "1098":"445967.0",
      "1099":"438372.0",
      "1100":"420056.0",
      "1101":"405504.0",
      "1121":"70735.4",
      "1122":"83306.4",
      "1123":"84224.1",
      "1124":"83817.2",
      "1125":"102896.8",
      "1126":"119167.1",
      "1127":"131104.4",
      "1128":"145930.2",
      "1129":"143344.2",
      "1130":"165264.5",
      "1131":"193168.3",
      "1132":"190154.3",
      "1133":"214840.5",
      "1134":"222120.4",
      "1135":"202973.2",
      "1136":"216560.4",
      "1137":"228871.1",
      "1138":"240998.3",
      "1139":"240678.4",
      "1140":"69591.8",
      "1141":"77908.0",
      "1142":"85594.9",
      "1143":"93333.4",
      "1144":"102157.9",
      "1145":"114552.9",
      "1146":"122499.7",
      "1147":"127625.5",
      "1148":"135477.9",
      "1149":"154014.0",
      "1150":"179996.0",
      "1151":"201459.4",
      "1152":"217160.3",
      "1153":"224077.6",
      "1154":"230058.8",
      "1155":"235746.1",
      "1156":"245157.9",
      "1157":"246966.5",
      "1158":"249143.1",
      "1159":"7532.8",
      "1160":"10917.2",
      "1161":"10757.1",
      "1162":"10309.5",
      "1163":"11768.7",
      "1164":"12397.6",
      "1165":"12585.6",
      "1166":"14099.4",
      "1167":"16555.6",
      "1168":"27295.7",
      "1169":"36728.8",
      "1170":"43937.9",
      "1171":"49445.7",
      "1172":"53429.3",
      "1173":"58489.2",
      "1174":"59494.1",
      "1175":"62911.0",
      "1176":"64647.1",
      "1177":"70866.8",
      "1235":"137290.4",
      "1236":"139698.4",
      "1237":"141568.7",
      "1238":"147003.5",
      "1239":"152384.5",
      "1240":"152216.2",
      "1241":"150761.7",
      "1242":"137041.3",
      "1243":"117793.5",
      "1244":"132923.8",
      "1245":"152145.1",
      "1246":"155866.9",
      "1247":"164084.3",
      "1248":"174063.4",
      "1249":"191540.0",
      "1250":"202783.0",
      "1251":"195313.5",
      "1252":"191209.5",
      "1253":"182698.2",
      "1178":"5483.6",
      "1179":"6035.5",
      "1180":"6707.8",
      "1181":"6943.8",
      "1182":"7427.5",
      "1183":"7690.1",
      "1184":"8201.5",
      "1185":"8013.6",
      "1186":"8262.5",
      "1187":"12517.5",
      "1188":"13916.2",
      "1189":"17216.6",
      "1190":"19417.7",
      "1191":"25520.1",
      "1192":"30219.9",
      "1193":"32087.4",
      "1194":"31756.0",
      "1195":"31862.7",
      "1196":"32222.9",
      "1197":"10953.5",
      "1198":"12369.5",
      "1199":"12274.1",
      "1200":"13125.0",
      "1201":"14977.1",
      "1202":"13945.3",
      "1203":"15496.3",
      "1204":"17194.1",
      "1205":"19616.1",
      "1206":"23305.7",
      "1207":"27910.3",
      "1208":"30952.7",
      "1209":"38030.6",
      "1210":"40677.5",
      "1211":"40802.4",
      "1212":"41384.2",
      "1213":"42159.8",
      "1214":"43369.5",
      "1215":"44321.9",
      "1254":"645942.9",
      "1255":"637004.1",
      "1256":"625646.4",
      "1257":"632116.9",
      "1258":"718656.8",
      "1259":"806349.1",
      "1260":"888713.3",
      "1261":"877421.4",
      "1262":"824108.1",
      "1263":"1103250.7",
      "1264":"1387555.0",
      "1265":"1590780.5",
      "1266":"1745862.0",
      "1267":"1798955.3",
      "1268":"2060437.7",
      "1269":"2270218.6",
      "1270":"2022759.2",
      "1271":"2013811.6",
      "1272":"2054921.6",
      "437":"66.1",
      "438":"66.7",
      "439":"66.7",
      "440":"65.9",
      "441":"65.2",
      "442":"68.6",
      "443":"67.3",
      "444":"65.0",
      "445":"68.7",
      "446":"79.9",
      "447":"82.7",
      "448":"82.4",
      "449":"81.9",
      "450":"81.3",
      "451":"84.0",
      "452":"84.9",
      "453":"82.9",
      "454":"78.3",
      "455":"74.0",
      "76":"109.6",
      "77":"108.2",
      "78":"105.4",
      "79":"101.7",
      "80":"97.2",
      "81":"95.1",
      "82":"91.5",
      "83":"87.3",
      "84":"93.2",
      "85":"100.2",
      "86":"100.3",
      "87":"103.5",
      "88":"104.8",
      "89":"105.5",
      "90":"107.0",
      "91":"105.2",
      "92":"104.9",
      "93":"101.8",
      "94":"100.0",
      "95":"70.7",
      "96":"64.5",
      "97":"51.0",
      "98":"43.4",
      "99":"35.7",
      "100":"26.6",
      "101":"20.9",
      "102":"16.3",
      "103":"13.0",
      "104":"13.7",
      "105":"15.4",
      "106":"15.2",
      "107":"16.7",
      "108":"17.1",
      "109":"27.1",
      "110":"26.0",
      "111":"29.3",
      "112":"25.3",
      "113":"22.3",
      "304":"55.7",
      "305":"57.3",
      "306":"60.5",
      "307":"63.8",
      "308":"64.8",
      "309":"63.4",
      "310":"59.3",
      "311":"54.0",
      "312":"45.6",
      "313":"54.3",
      "314":"56.4",
      "315":"65.9",
      "316":"80.3",
      "317":"104.0",
      "318":"109.2",
      "319":"107.5",
      "320":"103.4",
      "321":"93.9",
      "322":"100.6",
      "114":"17.0",
      "115":"22.8",
      "116":"25.9",
      "117":"28.3",
      "118":"28.5",
      "119":"27.9",
      "120":"27.7",
      "121":"27.5",
      "122":"28.3",
      "123":"33.6",
      "124":"37.4",
      "125":"39.8",
      "126":"44.5",
      "127":"44.9",
      "128":"42.2",
      "129":"40.0",
      "130":"36.8",
      "131":"34.7",
      "132":"32.6",
      "152":"59.1",
      "153":"57.9",
      "154":"59.7",
      "155":"63.3",
      "156":"65.0",
      "157":"67.3",
      "158":"66.7",
      "159":"64.0",
      "160":"65.5",
      "161":"73.0",
      "162":"82.4",
      "163":"79.8",
      "164":"81.1",
      "165":"78.7",
      "166":"75.7",
      "167":"72.1",
      "168":"69.2",
      "169":"65.3",
      "170":"61.9",
      "133":"52.4",
      "134":"48.5",
      "135":"49.1",
      "136":"46.2",
      "137":"44.2",
      "138":"37.4",
      "139":"31.5",
      "140":"27.3",
      "141":"33.3",
      "142":"40.2",
      "143":"42.6",
      "144":"46.1",
      "145":"44.9",
      "146":"44.0",
      "147":"44.3",
      "148":"39.8",
      "149":"37.2",
      "150":"35.5",
      "151":"34.2",
      "57":"69.1",
      "58":"68.1",
      "59":"68.1",
      "60":"69.4",
      "61":"69.7",
      "62":"70.5",
      "63":"68.5",
      "64":"66.1",
      "65":"69.8",
      "66":"80.4",
      "67":"85.9",
      "68":"87.8",
      "69":"90.9",
      "70":"92.8",
      "71":"93.0",
      "72":"91.0",
      "73":"90.2",
      "74":"87.9",
      "75":"86.1",
      "38":"69.0",
      "39":"68.0",
      "40":"68.0",
      "41":"69.3",
      "42":"69.6",
      "43":"70.3",
      "44":"68.3",
      "45":"65.9",
      "46":"69.6",
      "47":"80.2",
      "48":"85.8",
      "49":"87.6",
      "50":"90.7",
      "51":"92.6",
      "52":"92.8",
      "53":"90.8",
      "54":"90.0",
      "55":"87.8",
      "56":"85.9",
      "171":"5.1",
      "172":"4.8",
      "173":"5.7",
      "174":"5.6",
      "175":"5.1",
      "176":"4.7",
      "177":"4.6",
      "178":"3.8",
      "179":"4.5",
      "180":"7.2",
      "181":"6.6",
      "182":"6.1",
      "183":"9.8",
      "184":"10.2",
      "185":"10.6",
      "186":"10.0",
      "187":"10.2",
      "188":"9.3",
      "189":"8.4",
      "209":"104.9",
      "210":"107.1",
      "211":"104.9",
      "212":"101.5",
      "213":"102.9",
      "214":"107.4",
      "215":"103.6",
      "216":"103.1",
      "217":"109.4",
      "218":"126.7",
      "219":"146.2",
      "220":"172.1",
      "221":"159.6",
      "222":"177.4",
      "223":"178.9",
      "224":"175.9",
      "225":"178.5",
      "226":"176.2",
      "227":"181.2",
      "228":"57.8",
      "229":"54.0",
      "230":"51.2",
      "231":"47.7",
      "232":"45.4",
      "233":"42.4",
      "234":"39.1",
      "235":"35.8",
      "236":"39.7",
      "237":"53.3",
      "238":"60.5",
      "239":"69.9",
      "240":"86.3",
      "241":"95.8",
      "242":"100.7",
      "243":"99.3",
      "244":"99.2",
      "245":"98.6",
      "246":"97.6",
      "19":"60.7",
      "20":"59.9",
      "21":"59.5",
      "22":"61.2",
      "23":"61.7",
      "24":"62.3",
      "25":"60.8",
      "26":"58.2",
      "27":"61.4",
      "28":"74.0",
      "29":"79.6",
      "30":"82.1",
      "31":"84.4",
      "32":"86.3",
      "33":"87.0",
      "34":"84.9",
      "35":"83.8",
      "36":"82.1",
      "37":"80.5",
      "0":"60.6",
      "1":"59.9",
      "2":"59.5",
      "3":"61.1",
      "4":"61.7",
      "5":"62.2",
      "6":"60.7",
      "7":"58.1",
      "8":"61.3",
      "9":"74.0",
      "10":"79.6",
      "11":"82.0",
      "12":"84.4",
      "13":"86.3",
      "14":"87.0",
      "15":"84.9",
      "16":"83.8",
      "17":"82.1",
      "18":"80.4",
      "551":"42.5",
      "552":"40.9",
      "553":"40.2",
      "554":"42.7",
      "555":"42.6",
      "556":"39.9",
      "557":"38.1",
      "558":"33.9",
      "559":"32.6",
      "560":"41.5",
      "561":"46.9",
      "562":"48.3",
      "563":"53.6",
      "564":"56.2",
      "565":"59.8",
      "566":"63.0",
      "567":"62.6",
      "568":"60.9",
      "569":"59.0",
      "247":"58.9",
      "248":"58.3",
      "249":"60.3",
      "250":"64.4",
      "251":"65.9",
      "252":"67.4",
      "253":"64.6",
      "254":"64.5",
      "255":"68.8",
      "256":"83.0",
      "257":"85.3",
      "258":"87.8",
      "259":"90.6",
      "260":"93.4",
      "261":"94.9",
      "262":"95.6",
      "263":"98.0",
      "264":"98.4",
      "265":"98.4",
      "266":"35.7",
      "267":"36.7",
      "268":"36.8",
      "269":"38.2",
      "270":"40.3",
      "271":"41.3",
      "272":"38.7",
      "273":"37.4",
      "274":"39.3",
      "275":"48.7",
      "276":"57.8",
      "277":"64.4",
      "278":"70.1",
      "279":"81.2",
      "280":"84.7",
      "281":"84.4",
      "282":"81.0",
      "283":"78.0",
      "284":"74.8",
      "380":"55.7",
      "373":"22.0"

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the json file in Assets (parallel to app dir) directory

Note that if you would have generated with ng new YourAppname- this assets directory exists same line with 'app' directory, and services should be child directory of app directory. May look like as below:

::app/services/myservice.ts

```
getOrderSummary(): Observable {
    // get users from api
    return this.http.get('assets/ordersummary.json')//, options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log("mock data" + response.json());
            return response.json();
        }
    )
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```